# why cant the build find module @angular upgrade static

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, angular2-routing

I am trying to setup angular 2 in visual studio 2015 asp.net core 1.1 and I am getting this error when I build.

[image]

The file in question in the image above is in the router folder

[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",

    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.1.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",


    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"

  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Here is the tsconfig.js

```
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/scripts/",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [

      "jasmine"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

the systemconfig.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {

            'npm:': 'lib/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'scripts',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js',

            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'

        },

        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

I have gulp scripts copying into the lib folder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and this is what worked for me.

If you have a look at the upgrade.d.ts file, inside VS 2015, you will notice that there is a red squiggle on the import statement for  **'@angular/upgrade/static'**

[image: upgrade.d.ts]

I searched the node-modules folder for this dependency and it wasn't there.
So I installed it by running the following command

**run npm i @angular/upgrade**

After the installation the error went away.

I hope this helps.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you're using npm, make sure you've added a reference to "@angular/upgrade" inside your package.json file.

e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.0", <------------------- Add this
```

Save the change then right-click -> "Restore Packages".  If you head over to your node_modules/@angular folder, you should now see the missing upgrade subfolder.